# Flag content in Drupal via external HTTP request

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm writing an iOS app that displays content from a website managed by Drupal. I figured how I can create views in Drupal for delivering the content as JSON to the app. But now I want to enable my logged-in users to flag content as their favorites. Users can create an account on the website and are also able to log in inside the app. Favorites are stored per user.

In Drupal this is implemented using the [Flag module](https://drupal.org/project/flag), which renders corresponding links for toggling the flags on the website. Those links point to a specific URL that also contains a token to prevent spoofing. Calling the URL without the token leads to access denial.

Now unfortunately I can't generate those tokens in my app. Is there a way to flag content without using the website?

I'm new to Drupal. All I need is basically a hint on how to implement my own HTTP APIs that allow external programs to manipulate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to write my own module that provides a menu callback entry. My `favorites_api.module` file looks like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function favorites_api_menu() {
    $items['node/%/favorite/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Mark as favorite',
        'page callback' => 'favorites_api_toggle_favorite',
        'page arguments' => array(1, 3),
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for above menu entry
 */
function favorites_api_toggle_favorite($entity_id, $action) {
    $favorites_flag = flag_get_flag('favorites') or die('no "favorites" flag defined');
    $favorites_flag->flag($action, $entity_id);

    // error handling and return message
    // ...
}
```

Now I can call `http://myurl/node/3/favorite/flag` to mark node 3 as favorite and `http://myurl/node/3/favorite/unflag` to unmark it.

Having to write a *menu* entry to create a custom URL action is a bit misleading, though...

Answer (score 0):

Download and enable the "session api" module (https://drupal.org/project/session_api).

As said when you create/edit a flag module in the "Flag access" section:

> Anonymous users may flag content if the Session API module is
>   installed.

Every anonymous users will have the same token (line 2358 in "flag.module" file):

```
md5(drupal_get_private_key() . $entity_id)
```

You can then build this token in your app if you can get the entity/node id (private key can be fixed and set in Drupal configuration).

Edit: you will have to add a permission for your flag name for anonymous user in the permissions. list

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the favorites flag is not global, which means favorites are stored per user. So a user must be logged in in order to mark content as favorite. And the token for logged-in users is built using the session ID. Further I don't think it's a good idea to store the private key of the page inside the app, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree about the private key storage, not so safe ... Further is the code in your own answer working? I mean you must be logged in to make that works.

Comment: Ok. You did not mention in your issue that you were able to log your app user in the Drupal site. I think this would be good if you could explain in your answer (or in your question) that you are able to log in your users and how. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. I added that fact to the question.

Comment: The approach I described in my answer is working good. But I don't consider it elegant. Do you probably know a better way?

Comment: Can not see a better way. I'm curious: how did you manage the login/auth between the Drupal website and your IOS app?

Comment: That's actually quite simple. You only need to do a POST request containing the user data to the same URL as the website does and use the returned cookie in later calls.